# execute one line of python with variable input from bash

Tags: python, bash

I want to write one line of python and wrap in such a way than it will run from bash.
I looked into it and the idea seemd possible but, I'd specifically like to incorporate a variable input.

As an illustrative example; Here's what worked:

```
python -c "print('my favorite number to itself is '+str(5**5))"
```

However, I'd like to have a variable input so I tried to pipe one in, but the following doesn't work:

```
5 | python -c "print('my favorite number to itself is '+str($1**$1))"
```

What can I do to keep it simple, keep it one line, and add a variable input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
i=5; python -c "print('my favorite number to itself is '+str($i**$i))"
```

Answer (score 1):

With xargs:

```
echo 5 | xargs -I {} python -c "print('my favorite number to itself is '+str({}**{}))"
```